# Kdenlive record audio-only voiceover?

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I would like to record a voiceover for a video sequence using Kdenlive. When I click the Clip Monitor tab, uncheck Video, check Audio, and then press the Record button, I am getting an error:

> Capture crashed, please check your parameters

I don't want a video recording from my webcam or screen. What parameters/settings do I need to record only audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this feature is [made simple with Kdenlive 19.04](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/CapturingAudio) (I was running 18.10).

1. install Kdenlive 19.04+
2. right click any audio track
3. click "Show Record Controls"
4. press the "Record" circle

This will record stereo audio, which can be mixed to mono using the Audio correction plugin called "Copy Channels".

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have KdenLive 19.12.3, but when I right click an audio track I don't get this option.  Is there a specific location on an audio track?

Comment: I have double-checked, and this does work in Kdenlive 19.12.3. Make sure you are right-clicking on an audio track and not a video track. Audio tracks have a speaker icon while video tracks have a film icon.

Answer (score 3):

In Kdenlive 20.04.3, I see the checkbox “Show Record Controls” on audio tracks but it doesn't do anything. I've found the audio record button in Audio Mixer (in View menu). I've also had to install **libqt5multimedia5-plugins** (`apt install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`).

Answer (score 3):

I took me a bit of time to find this as well since much of the online documentation is for older versions of Kdenlive.  In v20.+ (i suspect this is the same in v19) you'll need to right-click on the **left side** of the audio channel rather than on the audio timeline.

[image]

Then play the project in monitor mode and hit record at the sections you want to voice over.  A new audio clip will be created and added to your project.